# + operator concatenates unepectedly

Tags: angular, typescript

I know that in javascript the + operator can sometimes act as a concatenation operator rather than addition, but I am surprised that it is doing this for the code that I have:

```
private getDefaultWeeks(year:number):week[]{
  let date = new Date(year,0,1);
  var currentDate= new Date();
  currentDate = this.dateService.getFirstMonday(date);
  while (currentDate.getFullYear()<(year+1)) //gets stuck here
  ..............
  }
```

So in my example, the (year+1) will for example sometimes get translated into 20181

Given that year is already typed as a number, can someone explain to me why this is happening, and what is the best solution. I can pull year+1 into a new variable, but I instinctively feel like that is a variable that shouldn't need to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you typed it "number", if you call getDefaultWeeks with a string, it will be treated as a string (there won't be a cast).
Are you sure that you are calling getDefaultWeeks with a number ?

Comment: Oh really, is that true? I am used to the rather more strongly typed world of c#

Comment: @jazza1000 yes, because your typescript code will be transformed into javascript code, so no more types.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the case, you will need to cast it to a number: doing `(+year + 1)` should work. Remember that TS cannot actually cast it to a number automagically for you, and neither can it detect if it's a string at runtime. Even though this is a stop-gap solution, you will need to check why is `getDefaultWeeks()` being passed a string as a parameter.

Comment: Cheers, I was under the misapprehension that typing it as number would force it to be cast as number. I am sure that this must be the cause of the problem